# 'Cannot find AlbumArt in scope' after installing cocoapods & connecting the app to firebase. Xcode & SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swiftui

Yesterday I installed cocoapods and the firebase dependencies on my musicplayer app I am doing for a school project. I always create new branches to try it out in case it does not work. I am using the latest version of Xcode and the latest versions of firebase with mac osx Big Sur.

I have a couple of structs in my ContentView for example SongCell, Album, Song & AlbumArt.

I then have another swift file called PlayerView where I designed the view for the player when you play songs. There I have a Vstack where the Text and AlbumArt are being displayed. All this worked without any problems until I installed the podfile and connected the app to firebase. Then all of sudden I cannot build or run the app because 'AlbumArt cannot be found in scope' inside the PlayerView file.

Summary:

1. I have a struct called AlbumArt inside the ContentView
2. This struct is also used inside the PlayerView example:

AlbumArt(album: album, isWithText: false)

3. Before I installed cocoapods and firebase, everything worked fine
4. Now it 'cannot find AlbumArt in scope' inside the PlayerView
5. It seems like whatever struct I want to use from ContentView into the PlayerView, I get the 'cannot find in scope' so it seems to be a problem when using the structs inside the playerViews.
6. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance. I will post the code from ContentView,  PlayerView and the podfile below.

Code in ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase



struct Album : Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var image : String
    var songs : [Song]
}

struct Song : Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name : String
    var time : String
    
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var data : MyData
    @State private var currentAlbum : Album?
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ScrollView{
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false, content: {
                    LazyHStack{
                        ForEach(self.data.albums, id:\.self, content: {
                            album in
                                AlbumArt(album: album, isWithText: true).onTapGesture {
                                    self.currentAlbum = album
                                }
                    })
                    }
                            
                })
                LazyVStack{
                    if self.data.albums.first == nil {
                        EmptyView()
                        
                    }else {
                        ForEach((self.currentAlbum?.songs ?? self.data.albums.first?.songs) ??
                                            [Song(name:"Song 1", time: "3:11"),
                                              Song(name:"Song 2", time: "3:11"),
                                              Song(name:"Song 3", time: "3:11"),
                                              Song(name:"Song 4", time: "3:11"),
                                              Song(name:"Song 5", time: "3:11"),
                                              Song(name:"Song 6", time: "3:11")],
                        id: \.self,
                        content: {
                        song in
                            SongCell(album: currentAlbum ?? self.data.albums.first!, song: song)
                })
                    
                }
                    
                
            }.navigationTitle("Sinemark")
        }
    }
}

struct AlbumArt : View{
    var album : Album
    var isWithText : Bool
    var body: some View {
        ZStack (alignment: .bottom, content: {
        
            Image(album.image)
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 170, height: 200, alignment: .center)
            
            if isWithText == true {
            ZStack {
                Blur(style: .dark)
                Text(album.name).foregroundColor(.white)
            }.frame(height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                
        }
    }).frame(width: 170, height: 200,alignment: .center) .clipped().cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 10).padding(20)
            
                
    }
}

struct SongCell : View{
    var album : Album
    var song : Song
    var body: some View{
        NavigationLink(
            destination: PlayerView(album: album, song: song), label: {
                    HStack{
                            ZStack{
                                Circle().frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).foregroundColor(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.blue/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                Circle().frame(width: 20, height: 20, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/).foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
                            Text(song.name).bold()
                            Spacer()
                            Text(song.time)
                        }.padding(20)
            
            }).buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
    
}


}
```

Code in PlayerView:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI




struct PlayerView : View {
    var album : Album
    var song : Song
    

    
    @State var isPlaying : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(album.image).resizable().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            Blur(style: .dark).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            VStack{
        
                Spacer()
                AlbumArt(album: album, isWithText: false)
                Text(song.name).font(.title).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(.white)
                Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    
                    Color.white.cornerRadius(20).shadow(radius: 10)
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        Button(action: self.previous, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.left.circle").resizable()
                        }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
                        
                        Button(action: self.playPause, label: {
                            Image(systemName: isPlaying ? "pause.circle.fill" : "play.circle.fill").resizable()
                        }).frame(width: 70, height: 70, alignment: .center).padding()
                        
                        Button(action: self.next, label: {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.right.circle").resizable()
                        }).frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center).foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
                            
                        }
                    
                }.padding().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom).frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
                }
            }
        }
        
    func playPause() {
        self.isPlaying.toggle()
        
    }
    
    func next () {
        
    }
    
    func previous () {
        
    }
    
    
}
```

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
  platform :ios, '14.4'

target 'BandApp_MusicPlayer' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BandApp_MusicPlayer
    pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
    pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
    

  target 'BandApp_MusicPlayerTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'BandApp_MusicPlayerUITests' do
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: This might be obvious, but did you try to clean the project and rebuild?

Comment: @JohnNimis, Yes I did, it then builds slowly until the error show up again. Its funny because it is the only error I have, I even fixed all the warnings as well.

Comment: That is strange. Was Firebase your first cocoapod you added? It's possible that `pod init` or `pod install` messed with your project, especially if you had it open when you ran those commands. You can check your Project and Target settings, also check Target Membership inside the File Inspector for your source files?

Comment: Yes its the first cocoapod I added. I might had it open while I installed it, I checked target membership and all the source files seem to be there. Another thing I tried was to move the whole struct code inside the ContentView and placed it above the ContentView struct. I did not get any errors when I ran the application but the simulator does not show the albums or the songs, only the artist name with a white background so I undid it back to how it was before.

Comment: Describing your issue is great but without actual code, we are just guessing. Instead of telling us about your Struct, include it. Instead of telling us about your podfile, include it. Your issue is most likely a missing bracket } in your code so the compiler doesn't where where the code starts and ends. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). update your question and we'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, you are right I will do that. I tried to post screenshots but I do not have enough points for that yet, will update the question now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `AlbumArt` struct definition is internal to the `ContentView` struct, so it is out of scope from the perspective of `PlayerView`. You might as well do the same for SongCell as well, you don't have to define it inside the `ContentView` struct.

If you move that `struct` definition to the root level of your swift file, it will compile.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  // all your ContentView stuff
}

struct AlbumArt : View {
  // this definition here
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer John! You were right, it works now :D I moved the structs outside the ContentView as you told me. Forever grateful for the help!

Comment: @DavidSävenmark Great, glad it worked! Would you mind marking this answer as "accepted"? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I see you problem - you have placeholder code in your AlbumArt class:

`/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/`

It appears in this part of your code:

```
if isWithText == true {
    ZStack {
        Blur(style: .dark)
        Text(album.name).foregroundColor(.white)
    }.frame(height: 60, alignment: .center) <--- RIGHT HERE
}
```

Let me know if that fixes it!

Comment: Appreciate the help! I edited the placeholder by writing .center manually but the error remains. I also notice how there are lots of more tasks now when it builds so it takes longer time.